# Two functions don't work properly in tkinter python with sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I've got a problem w with my program "phonebook" with sqlite3. There are 2 functions doesn't work properly with treeview in tkinter. When I try to update one selected row it updated all rows/records in sqlite but in treeview is correctly one updated record, and when I try delete one selected row it deletes all datas from sqlite whereas in treeview is deleted one selected row. I suppose there is no connection between treeview and sqlite3. I don't know what the problem is.

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import OperationalError
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
root=Tk()
root.title("Phonebook")
root.geometry("460x600")
one = StringVar()
two = StringVar()
three = StringVar()
def create_sql():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile (First TEXT, Surname TEXT, phone_number TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
def get_row(event):
    try:
        cursor = tree.focus()
        content = tree.item(cursor)
        row = content["values"]
        one.set(row[0])
        two.set(row[1])
        three.set(row[2])
    except IndexError:
        pass
def update_selcted_row():
    data1 = one.get()
    data2 = two.get()
    data3 = three.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=? """, (data1, data2, data3))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
def del_sel():
    data1 = one.get()
    data2 = two.get()
    data3 = three.get()
    try:
        selected_item = tree.selection()[0] 
        tree.delete(selected_item)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM profile WHERE First=? AND Surname=? AND phone_number=?",(data1, data2, data3))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
#Labels
lb= Label(root,text="Firstname:",font=("calibri",15))
lb.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5,sticky=E)
lb1= Label(root,text="Lastname: ",font=("calibri",15))
lb1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=5,sticky=E)
lb2= Label(root,text="Phone number",font=("calibri",15))
lb2.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=5,sticky=E)
#buttons
but1 = Button(root,text="Update\nselected row",width=13,command=update_selected_row)
but1.grid(row=6,column=0,pady=5)
but4 = Button(root,text="Delete\nselected",width=13,command=del_sel)
but4.grid(row=7,column=0,pady=5)
#entries
e = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=one)
e.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
e1 = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=two)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
e2 = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=three)
e2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
#treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=10)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=130)
tree.column("three",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Imię")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwisko")
tree.heading("three", text="Nr Telefonu")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=6,padx=20)
tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",get_row)
create_sql()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need a WHERE clause in `UPDATE` statement.  Your `DELETE` statement should work fine.  Also you forgot to update the treeview inside `update_selected_row()` function.

Comment: I did it cur.execute("""UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=? WHERE First=? AND Surname=? AND phone_number=? """, (data1, data2, data3)) It raises an error: cur.execute("""UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=? WHERE First=? AND Surname=? AND phone_number=? """, (data1, data2, data3))
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 6, and there are 3 supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a WHERE clause in `UPDATE` statement:

```
def update_selected_row():
    # original data
    cursor = tree.focus()
    content = tree.item(cursor)
    row = content["values"]
    # new data
    data1 = one.get()
    data2 = two.get()
    data3 = three.get()
    # update database
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=? WHERE First=? AND Surname=? AND phone_number=?""",
                (data1, data2, data3, row[0], row[1], row[2]))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    # update treeview
    tree.item(cursor, values=(data1, data2, data3))
```

**EDIT**: update code with unique id field in database table:

```
from tkinter import*
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import OperationalError
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

root=Tk()
root.title("Phonebook")
root.geometry("460x600")

one = StringVar()
two = StringVar()
three = StringVar()
rowid = StringVar()

def create_sql():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    # added id field
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS profile (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, First TEXT, Surname TEXT, phone_number TEXT)")
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM profile")
    for rec in cur:
        tree.insert('', 'end', iid=rec[0], values=rec[1:])
    conn.close()

def get_row(event):
    try:
        cursor = tree.focus()
        content = tree.item(cursor)
        row = content["values"]
        rowid.set(cursor)
        one.set(row[0])
        two.set(row[1])
        three.set(row[2])
    except IndexError:
        pass

def add_record():
    data1 = one.get()
    data2 = two.get()
    data3 = three.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""INSERT INTO profile VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)""", (data1, data2, data3))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    # update treeview
    tree.insert('', 'end', iid=cur.lastrowid, values=(data1, data2, data3))

def update_selected_row():
    id = rowid.get()
    # new data
    data1 = one.get()
    data2 = two.get()
    data3 = three.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""UPDATE profile SET First=?, Surname=?, phone_number=? WHERE id=?""", (data1, data2, data3, id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    # update treeview
    tree.item(id, values=(data1, data2, data3))

def del_sel():
    id = rowid.get()
    data1 = one.get()
    data2 = two.get()
    data3 = three.get()
    try:
        selected_item = tree.selection()[0] 
        tree.delete(selected_item)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    conn = sqlite3.connect("phone_book.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM profile WHERE id=?", (id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
#Labels
lb= Label(root,text="Firstname:",font=("calibri",15))
lb.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=5,sticky=E)
lb1= Label(root,text="Lastname: ",font=("calibri",15))
lb1.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=10,pady=5,sticky=E)
lb2= Label(root,text="Phone number",font=("calibri",15))
lb2.grid(row=2,column=0,padx=10,pady=5,sticky=E)
#buttons
but1 = Button(root,text="Update\nselected row",width=13,command=update_selected_row)
but1.grid(row=6,column=0,pady=5)
but4 = Button(root,text="Delete\nselected",width=13,command=del_sel)
but4.grid(row=7,column=0,pady=5)
but5 = Button(root,text="Add\nRecord",width=13,command=add_record)
but5.grid(row=8,column=0,pady=5)
#entries
e = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=one)
e.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
e1 = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=two)
e1.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
e2 = Entry(root,bd=2,textvariable=three)
e2.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=10,pady=5)
#treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=10)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=130)
tree.column("three",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Imię")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwisko")
tree.heading("three", text="Nr Telefonu")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=4,column=0,columnspan=6,padx=20)
tree.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",get_row)
create_sql()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But when it comes to delete function there is one bug. Let's suppose we've got two the same looking/writen/added records/rows in treeview/sqlite3. When I match one of them it deletes both or when I've got more then two the same records. How to avoid it?

Comment: Base on your table definition, you cannot fix it. You need to add a field in the table to identify the record uniquely.

Comment: Do I have to add column with id number?

Comment: Yes, an auto-increment id number.

Comment: In this case the delete statement will look like DELETE FROM profile WHERE First=? AND Surname=? AND phone_number=? id=?",(data1, data2, data3). That's all or sth more ?

Comment: If the id is unique, just `cur.execute("DELETE FROM profile WHERE id = ?", (id,))`.  But you need to find a way to get the id.

Comment: I have updated my answer with unique id field added to the database table.

Comment: Hey could you please look at my question/post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63337545/how-to-import-data-from-csv-to-treeview-and-sqlite3-tkinter-using-python it comes to importing data from csv to treeview tkinter and sqlite3