# Querying in Database sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, tkinter

I try to write function for my project, which allows user partial search and highlights rows/records according to column "name" with sqlite3 statements. But I don't know how to write the function that it works with SQLite3 statement and matches rows/records in treeview.

```
def saerch_medicine():
 #query with sqlite3
    conn = sqlite3.connect("pharmacy.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    conn.commit()
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM medicine WHERE name LIKE '%"name_column"%'")
   selections=[] 
     for i in cur:
         tree. selections[0] 
    conn.close()

bt6 = Button(root,text="Search according column name", width=10, command=search)
bt6.grid(row=11, column=1, pady=10, padx=20)
e6 = Entry(root, width=20)
e6.grid(row=11, column=3, pady=10, padx=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the first column in the `tree` is the `name` column, then modify `saerch_medicine()` (should `saerch` be `search` instead?) as below:

```py
def saerch_medicine():
    srch_name = e6.get().strip()
    if srch_name:
        conn = sqlite3.connect("pharmacy.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT name FROM medicine WHERE name LIKE "%{}%"'.format(srch_name))
        matched = [rec[0] for rec in cur]
        conn.close()
        items = [row for row in tree.get_children() if tree.item(row, 'values')[0] in matched]
        tree.selection_set(items)
```

However if all the records have been inserted into `tree`, I think you can search the `tree` directly:

```py
def saerch_medicine():
    srch_name = e6.get().strip()
    if srch_name:
        rows = [row for row in tree.get_children() if srch_name in tree.item(row, 'values')[0]]
        tree.selection_set(rows)
```

Comment: Hmm I don't know why but it matches nothing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63011692/two-functions-dont-work-properly-in-tkinter-python-with-sqlite3 the rest code is simmilar to it.

Comment: Try to print out `matched` and see whether records are fetched.

Comment: Print(matched) Yes it printed searched item but it didn't highlight

Comment: Then is `name` column the first column in treeview?  Better post the code how you create the treeview.

Comment: ok now it works items = [row for row in tree.get_children() if tree.item(row, 'values')[1] in matched] changed to 1

Comment: I've got one question left. Do I need add "conn.commit()" after cur.sql_statemnet? Because there wasn't it.

Comment: It is required if the SQL statement modifies the database, i.e. UPDATE or DELETE.  It is not necessary if it is SELECT statement.

Comment: Hey I posted another question, but this includes antoher problem. It's about Date expiry. Could you check it please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63088753/dateexpiry-in-sqlite3-python?noredirect=1#comment111563257_63088753