# DateExpiry in Sqlite3 Python

Tags: python, sqlite, date, tkinter

I try to figure out how to write function with SQLite3 statement which is responsible for informing me about expiry date of any medicine in advance let's suppose 30 days. I did sth like this but it doesn't work properly

```
l1top = Label(fr,text="Number of serie:")
l1top.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,sticky=E,pady=10)
l2top = Label(fr,text="Name of medicine:")
l2top.grid(row=1,column=0,padx=20,sticky=E,pady=10)
l3top = Label(fr,text="Dose")
l3top.grid(row=3,column=0,padx=20,sticky=E,pady=10)
l4top = Label(fr,text="Type of medicine")
l4top.grid(row=4,column=0,padx=20,sticky=E,pady=10)
l5top = Label(fr,text="Packages:")
l5top.grid(row=5,column=0,padx=20,sticky=E,pady=10)
l5top = Label(fr,text="Bottles:")
l5top.grid(row=6,column=0,padx=20,sticky=E,pady=10)
l6top = Label(fr,text="Expiry Date:")
l6top.grid(row=7,column=0,padx=20,sticky=E,pady=10)
def expiry():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("pharmacy.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT date FROM medicine WHERE date <= 30')
    matched = [rec[0] for rec in cur]
    conn.close()
    items = [row for row in tree.get_children() if tree.item(row, 'values')[6] in matched]
    tree.selection_set(items)
expiry()
```

The code above doesn't select properly because it matches only according to days but it does not include the whole date from the widget DateEntry(below). How to rewrite the SQLite statement that it grabs the whole date and matches all products with date which expiry ends in 30 days and highlights on red the last column ([6]) with date.

```
e6 = DateEntry(fr,width=12,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=2020,state="readonly",date_pattern="dd/mm/yyyy",textvariable=six)
e6.grid(row=7,column=1,pady=10)
```

Comment: what does the `date` column in your `medicine` table signify? It would help if you provided a few rows of the table and show the expected output.

Comment: I set expiry date

Comment: What is the format of the column `date`?

Comment: Please show some [data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your odds of getting a good response.

Comment: cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS medicine(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, number TEXT, name TEXT, dose TEXT, face TEXT, package TEXT, amp TEXT, date TEXT)")

Comment: format of column is for example 12/07/2020

Comment: Change the format of the dates in the table to YYYY-MM-DD. This is the only valide date format for SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format of the column `date` is `DD-MM-YYYY`, first you must change it to `YYYY-MM-DD`, because this is the only valid format for SQLite:

```
UPDATE medicine 
SET date = SUBSTR(date, -4) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 4, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(date, 1, 2);
```

and then use the function `DATE()` to get the rows where `date` is between *now* and *now + 30 days*:

```
SELECT date 
FROM medicine 
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE('now') AND DATE('now', '+30 day')
```

Comment: Ok it works but when to do it it highlights only 6th column on red